# Dual NIC Configured as Router with NAT

Tags: networking, iptables, netplan, routing, nic

I have a PC running Ubuntu 18.04 and am attempting to configure the two GbE interfaces as a gateway/router.  I've referred to some related questions and attempted to follow guides such as this one: [How to make a simple router\gateway from Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS](https://medium.com/@exesse/how-to-make-a-simple-router-gateway-from-ubuntu-server-18-04-lts-fd40b7bfec9).

The high-level intent is for one of the NICs to be a "WAN" interface (enp2s0) receiving its address, nameservers, gateway, etc via DHCP from another router further up the stream (18.1.0.0/24), while the other NIC serves as a "LOCAL" interface (enp0s31f6) connected to a number of devices with statically assigned addresses under an alternate subnet (192.168.0.0/24).  The desired behavior is for devices connected on the static "Layer 2" network (192.168.0.0/24) to be able to reach the WAN "Layer 3" network (18.1.0.0/24) which may, in turn, provide access out to the internet depending upon configuration.  To do this, there needs to be SNAT between the two subnets.

Here is a network topology diagram for reference:
[Dual NIC Gateway/Router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuoWU.jpg)

What I am seeing using the configuration below is that devices on the "LOCAL" network (192.168.0.0/24) can access other devices on the same subnet, can access the WAN interface itself at its 18.1.0.0/24 address (which is actually allocated by DHCP), but cannot successfully reach beyond the WAN interface to other 18.1.0.0/24 devices on that network (pinging known devices at 18.1.0.0/24 addresses returns no route to host).

I have attempted to configure the interfaces via netplan as below:

```
network:
  ethernets:
      enp2s0:
        #WAN
        dhcp4: yes
        dhcp4-overrides:
          route-metric: 100
        gateway4: 18.1.0.1
        nameservers: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
      enp0s31f6:
        #LOCAL
        addresses:
        - 192.168.0.1/24
        dhcp4: no
  version: 2
```

Then I enabled IP forwarding via
`sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf`  and uncommenting `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

Finally (after reboot) I configured IP tables for the SNAT and basic firewall rules via:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i enp2s0 -o enp0s31f6 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

To test, I connected a device to the "LOCAL" NIC (192.168.0.0/24) with a static address reservation within that subnet (192.168.0.99/24 for test) and with the gateway set to the gateway NIC's address (192.168.0.1 in this example). I am able to "see" (ping) the gateway and other devices statically assigned on the 192.168.0.0/24 subnet and the address of the WAN NIC itself (assigned by DHCP, currently 18.1.0.94) without issue, but cannot reach (ping) any other devices on the 18.1.0.0/24 subnet that I know are there.

I'd greatly appreciate any tips on what I might be missing in the configuration here!

#### Update w/ IP Tables save

Per request in the comments, here is the rules file that the above iptables commands created (rules.v4):

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Wed Sep  2 16:25:54 2020
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [117:21241]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [103:6753]
-A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Sep  2 16:25:54 2020
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Wed Sep  2 16:25:54 2020
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [18:1766]
:INPUT ACCEPT [18:1766]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [70:5183]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [70:5183]
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Sep  2 16:25:54 2020
```

Comment: Does your device at 192.168.0.99 know that the gateway to the WAN is 192.168.0.40? i.e. does it know that the route to 10.1.0.0/24 is via 192.168.0.40?

Comment: Yeah, I've explicitly told the other statically assigned 192.168.0.0/24 devices that they should use 192.168.0.40 as their gateway.

Comment: " I am able to "see" (ping) the gateway and other devices statically assigned on the 192.168.0.0/24 subnet without issue, but cannot reach (ping) any devices on the 10.1.0.0/24 subnet that I know are there.".... yeah but does that subnet know that the other is there? Does it know where to return the nat'd traffic?

Comment: @WU-TANG would I need to add a rule in iptables for DNAT based on that?  Do you happen to know what rule would make that work?  It sounds plausible that could be the issue given "ping" would need to be able to get the response back.

Comment: No, the other devices on 10.1.0.0/24 should see the ping as from your server 10.1.0.0/24 address and return to that address. Your iptables rule set assumes the default policy of ACCEPT, is that true? perhaps post the outputs from `sudo iptables -v -x -n -L` and `sudo iptables -t nat -v -x -n -L`. We can also then observe the counters. Also run tcpdump, or wireshark if you prefer, and observe the actual packet traffic. For FORWARD try this `sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i enp2s -o enp0s34 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`

Comment: Hello... No, nothing to do with firewalls or NAT... Do the other devices on the other network know where to send traffic? It doesn't happen automatically. Just like it didn't happen automatically for the 192.x.x.x outgoing traffic. For clarity you probably should have shown the "any devices on the 10.1.0.0/24 subnet that I know are there" devices on your diagram. You didn't speak a lot about that network and if it was functioning correctly.

Comment: Can you post the output of `sudo iptables-save` from your router PC?  Also, can you double check that forwarding is enabled by doing `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` and checking it's a "1"?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll post these outputs when I get back in on Monday

Comment: Okay, here's what I've got so far.  @BrianTurek `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` returns "1"

I have tried adding the FORWARD rule that you suggested @DougSmythies.  Apologies the interface names are different than I posted and I've updated them in the question as well as the WAN network is actually 18.1.0.0/24.

Overall, from another device on the 192.168.0.0/24 subnet (say 192.168.0.99) whose gateway is set to match the LOCAL interface's static address, I can ping the gateway and I can ping the 18.1.0.0/24 subnet ip of the WAN interface, but cannot ping other devices on 18.1.0.0/24.

Comment: Can you please post the output of `sudo iptables-save`?  Your forward rules probably aren't doing what you want (you don't have a NEW state) but that shouldn't be causing problems unless you changed your default policy to DROP.

Comment: We can not help without the information we have asked for. Either in the form @BrianTurek asked for, or the form I asked for, or both.

Answer (score 1):

For those who find this question again, I have discovered the cause if not the solution.  Our system's **Docker** configuration was adding rules to the IP tables that in some way interfered with the NIC routing functions.  With that Docker installation removed, the configuration described in the question works as expected!

Comment: Hi, this is exactly the problem I am having. I cannot remove the Docker installation, so do you know perhaps more specifically which rule(s) where causing the issue? Even if I try to clean up the iptables , the problem persists..! The strange this is that ping from WAN side works, which means the ping reply sends back from local network to WAN , but ping from LAN to outside does not work and it gets me crazy..!